# UpdatePanel on just one gridview column?

Tags: ajax

Is it possible to put UpdatePanel on just one of Gridview Columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28VS.90%29.aspx) would have to update several disjointed `<td>` elements instead of a single `<table>`. To my knowledge, that's not possible.

But maybe you could put one `UpdatePanel` with [UpdateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) set to `Always` around the contents of each `<td>` (using e.g. a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx)).